# Acces to file system/directory path from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

It is possible to get browser directory using javascript? I need to have acces to user file system from firefox addon, it is even possible?

Second question related to first one. I need to save file in hardcoded directory - path from where i run my portable firefox, it is possible?

Comment: from firefox addon ?

Comment: yes you can for sure

Comment: @FastSnail I edited question with additional information

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_the_main_thread 
Was very helpful for this one